# Better way to do custom Rails Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to set up a basic calendar function that will show the number of articles posted for a given day. Thus I need a query that gives the date and a count for that day from my table. Right now I'm doing this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(created_at) FROM 'articles' GROUP BY DATE(created_at)")
```

which returns something like:

```
[{"COUNT(*)"=>1, "DATE(created_at)"=>"2011-05-09", 0=>1, 1=>"2011-05-09"
{"COUNT(*)"=>2, "DATE(created_at)"=>"2011-05-12", 0=>2, 1=>"2011-05-12"}, 
{"COUNT(*)"=>2, "DATE(created_at)"=>"2011-05-13", 0=>2, 1=>"2011-05-13"},
... etc.
```

However, this seems like a really bad way to do this particular thing. I'd also like to be able to chain this with other scopes I've set up so instead I could do something like:

```
Article.no_spam.date_counts
```

and get a similar result. Is there a more Rails-y way to do this? I'm using Rails 3.

**EDIT:** No-one answered, I found an ugly, but workable solution, in case any one needs it in the future. However, if there's a better way to do this, please let me know:
Here's my code (in Article.rb):

```
def self.datecount
    #this query is a mega hack, but it alows me to chain Article scopes nicely
    counts = select("COUNT(created_at) as id, created_at").group("DATE(created_at)")
    out = {}
    counts.each do |a|
        out[a.created_at.to_date] = a.id
    end
    out
end
```

this does allow me to chain my scopes how I want Article.no_spam.datecount returns a hash of {dates => counts}, and I can add other scopes on the stack too. It's just so ugly inside...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
Article.group('DATE(created_at)').count
```

You'll get a hash of `created_at` dates to `count`s of articles created on that date.

Comment: Yup, thanks, I just figured that out, WAAAAAY Simpler that way.

Comment: It's sort of unintuitive syntax in my mind, since you expect count to return an int, but it works well!

Answer (score -1):

Better way for `self.datecount` is

```
out = counts.group_by(&:created_at)
```

or

```
out = counts.map{|a| [a.created_at.to_date, a.id] }.group_by(&:first)
```